# Ball collisions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

When two balls collide directly, the impulse of the collision acts along the line of centers, so the momentum along this direction is not conserved. Therefore, I can only use the conservation of momentum perpendicular to this direction:

[image]

But in this question (A is twice mass of B):

[image]

I had to use conservation of momentum in both directions to get an answer, ignoring impulse entirely. My guess is that it has something to do with the time of collision, if it is small enough then impulse is negligible. But I don't understand where and when I can assume that because the question doesn't state it. Any help?

Comment: Why do you think momentum is not conserved overall?

Comment: Momentum is conserved in the absence of external forces, of which there are none in this scenario. With no outside forces, overall momentum is conserved on *all* axes, but each individual ball's momentum need not be conserved on *any* axis.

Comment: If you are conserving momentum of the *system* then there is no external force on system, thus momentum of system can be conserved.

Comment: Momentum of a single ball doesn't need to be conserved. But the momentum of the whole system MUST be because action reaction pair of Impulse/Force would cancel out each other.

Comment: @Nuclear Hoagie I agree, my point was that the momentum of a single ball is not conserved (because of the impulse), yet to answer the question I had to assume that it was conserved. This differs from the textbook I quoted.

Comment: @ED2468 The momentum vector of each ball points in *different directions* before and after the collisions, momentum cannot possibly be conserved for each ball individually. Ball A is moving down and to the right before the collision and directly right after, clearly those aren't the same momentums. For Ball A's momentum to be conserved, its mass and velocity would need to remain the same before and after the collision, meaning there's no collision at all. The picture clearly shows A with different momentums before and after, how do you figure momentum is conserved for A?

Answer (score 0):

Total momentum is conserved due to Newton's 3rd law. Momentum is exchanged along the line connecting the centers such that if $+J$ is added to one body $-J$ is removed from the other body.

So if the total momentum before impact along the line of contact was $p_1 + p_2$, then after the contact it is $$(p_1-J) + (p_2 + J) = p_1 + p_2$$